# Multiple validations in a single column in 2013

Tags: 2013, column, validation, syntax

I have been working on something I feel should be very simple for far too long. I have a single line text column in a list and would like to employee multiple validations to the column. The requirements are as follows:

Entries must be a number
Numbers must be between 170000000 and 180000000
Or number must be 0

Can someone assist me with what the syntax should be to get all three to work?

Comment: Make it a number column imo, it'll be easier to do validation, > 0 or ( >= 170000000 and <=180000000)

Comment: There is a reason that I am not using a number column.

Comment: You need the ``OR`` , ``AND`` and ``VALUE`` functions, see http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Not certain how I would use the VALUE function in this case. Here is an example of what I did using OR, AND and ISNUMBER and SharePoint did accept it as a valid formula but when I tested it I would continue to get my error message regardless if the answer was correct or not.

Comment: =OR([Column Name]=0,AND(ISNUMBER([Column Name]+0),[Column Name]>170000000,[Column Name]<180000000))